# Can't add another table (migration) into project ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, database-migration

My project is supposed to have 2 tables: articles and categories with one-to-many relation (article can have only one category but category can be owned by many articles) between each other. I tried to add table Articles (with category as just a string field) first and it passed successfully (table has been created). Then I add Category class and add some fields into Article class. Now I have smth like this:

```
public class Article
  {  

    public int Id {get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] HeroImage { get; set; }        
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }

    public Category()
    {
        Articles = new List<Article>();
    }
}
```

After all thee changes I changed Context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

}
```

And then I try to add migration (Add-Migration Categories -> Update-Database), passed without any mistakes but nothing changes! Table Categories hasn't been created and even table Articles hasn't been changed. Please, any help.

Comment: The only one I have rn is some class ...-Categories  in Data->Migrations

Comment: Could you show us the Migration file that should be created when you execute `Add-Migration Categories`?

Comment: @Ronald Haan `namespace MyBlog.Data.Migrations
{
    public partial class Categories : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
}
`

Comment: Are you using .Net Core or .Net Framework?

Comment: @RonaldHaan, .NET Core 2.1.

Comment: Did you configure your `ApplicationDbContext` in the method `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` in `Startup.cs`?

Comment: It should look like this `// Register Entity Framework service
            services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
                    options.UseSqlServer(<connectionstring>);
                });`

Comment: @RonaldHaan, yes, I did: ` services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();`

Comment: And the `"DefaultConnection"` in `AppSettings.json` Exists?

Comment: @RonaldHaan, yes, I  have already created table successfully.

Comment: if feel there is something missing in your question your entity is perfect and should work without any issue , check you db and refresh the database . i tried the same and works for me

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove last migration

```
dotnet ef migrations remove --force
```

2. Create migration again

```
dotnet ef migrations add <Name>
```

3. Check that method "Up" in your migration has code for creating table and changing fields names of Article table.
4. Update database

```
dotnet ef database update
```